# indexing within parfor loop - matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I'm trying to run this code in Matlab

```
a = ones(4,4);

b=[1,0,0,1;0,0,0,1;0,1,0,0;0,0,0,0];
b(:,:,2)=[0,1,1,0;1,1,1,0;1,0,1,1;1,1,1,1];

parfor i = 1:size(b,3)
    c = b(:,:,i)
    a(c) = i;

end
```

but get the error:

```
Error: The variable a in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

Answer (score 4):

There are restrictions in how you can write into arrays inside the body of a `parfor loop`. In general, you will need to use [sliced arrays](https://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html).

The reason behind this issue is that Matlab needs to prevent that different worksers access the same data, leading to unpredictable results (as the timely order in which the `parfor` loops through `i` is not detemined).

So, although in your example the workers don't operate on the same entries of `a`, due to the way how you index `a` (with an array of logicals), it is currently not possible for Matlab to decide if this is the case or not (in other words, Matlab cannot *classify* `a`).

Edit: For completeness I add some code that is equivalent to your example, although I assume that your actual problem involves more complicated logical indexing?

```
a = ones(4,4,4);

parfor i = 1:size(a,1)
    a(i, :, :) = zeros(4, 4) + i;  % this is sliced indexing
end
```

Edit: As the OP example was modified, the above code is not equivalent to the example anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. However, I'm still not sure how to slice my data. I have tried several ways but always get the same error message meaning I'm not slicing the data properly. I updated my question with a more realistic example, although my code involves multidimensional arrays but to simplify I used a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: I believe that it is not possible with `parfor`, sorry. But maybe a more experienced Matlab user has some idea how to do it?

Comment: If the thing that you do in your loop involves some considerable computational workload, you can still use parfor to do these computations and store them in some other array that can be sliced, and then use an ordinary `for` loop to store the results in the pattern that you wish. However, if the parallelization is meant only to accelerate writing data into the given nd-array format, I see little hope.

Comment: Not only little hope, but if it were possible, it would be a pessimization over a normal `for`. `parfor` should only be used for heavy computation.